# como hacer una vista simple de una columna en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

buenas actualmente me encuentro haciendo una aplicacion de una biblioteca en laravel en la cual empleo un foreach para mostrar los valores de la tabla libros de la siguientes manera:

```
@foreach($libros as $libro)

<img src="libreria/app/{{$libro->path}}" alt="" />
</div>
<a class="span" href="ver"> 
<i>{{$libro->titulo}}</i></a>
<p class="info">IDIOMA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$libro->idioma}}</p>
<p class="info">PAGINAS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$libro->paginas}}</p>
<p class="info">CATEGORIA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$libro->categoria}}</p>
<p class="info">VOLUMENES DISPONIBLES:&nbsp;&nbsp; {{$libro->cantidad}}</p>
</div>
```

mi pregunta es como puedo hacer una vista individual de cada columna que envie al metodo "ver" al que esta enviando cada columna ?

Answer (score 0):

Creando una subvista, algo rápido sería así:

```
@foreach($libros as $libro)

  <img src="libreria/app/{{$libro->path}}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <a class="span" href="ver"> 
    <i>{{$libro->titulo}}</i></a>
    @include('ver', ['libro' => $libro, 'texto' => 'IDIOMA'])
    @include('ver', ['libro' => $libro, 'texto' => 'PAGINAS'])
    @include('ver', ['libro' => $libro, 'texto' => 'CATEGORIAS'])
    @include('ver', ['libro' => $libro, 'texto' => 'VOLUMENES'])
    </div>
```

ver.blade.php

```
<p class="info">{{$texto}}:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$libro->idioma}}</p>
```

Seguramente se puede mejorar el código para no hacerlo tan redundante a la hora de incluir las subvistas, pero esto te da la idea de como resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias por responder pero no me funciono, esperaba algo que trabajara en base al id de la base para redireccionar

Comment: "En base al id de la base para redireccionar" ¿eso qué quiere decir?